# async function: Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function that takes an auth method as a param and uses the auth method as a login option.

Sonarcloud throws the following error on the handleAuthorisationOnClick function

```
Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected.
```

```
const handleAuthorisationOnClick = async (authMethod: string): Promise<void> => {

   loginWithRedirect({
      connection: authMethod,
      ...
    });
};
```

I pass handleAuthorisationOnClick as a prop to a modal component AuthorisationModal

```
<AuthorisationModal
          onAuthMethodSelected={handleAuthorisationOnClick} <----- Sonarcloud error
    ...
```

AuthorisationModal maps through the auth methods and passes the auth method as a param to onAuthMethodSelected

```
const AuthorisationModal = ({onAuthMethodSelected}) => (
          {methods.map((connectionName: string) => (
            <Button
              onClick={() => onAuthMethodSelected(connectionName)}
          
            >
              {methods.label}
            </Button>
          ))}
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sonarcloud is warning you of a potential bug: you're passing a function that returns a promise to something that isn't expecting to receive a promise when calling the function. The warning is useful, because it's a common mistake. It's best not to pass functions returning promises (including `async` functions) as callbacks when the caller won't use the promise. If the caller isn't expecting a promise, it's not going to handle promise rejection, which may lead to an unhandled rejection error in your program.

If it's really okay that the function does its work asynchronously, wrap it in a non-`async` function that *will* handle promise rejection (by reporting the error to the user, ideally), and pass *that* function to the code that isn't expecting to handle a promise.

Rough sketch of what that wrapper would look like:

```
const wrapper = () => {
    handleAuthorisationOnClick()
    .catch((error) => {
        // Report the error to the user
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am having a similar issue, my question here is that if I use await syntax here, I need to use async in front of wrapper. This time I will have the same error, right? How to do same with async / await syntax?

Comment: @ÖmerKeskinkilic - You never *have* to use `await`, it's "just" syntactic sugar on promises. But you can do the same as the above using an `async` function by ensuring all of the function's contents are in a `try`/`catch`: `const wrapper = async () => { try { await handleAuthorisationClick(); } catch (error) { /* Report the error to the user *? } };`